# Is it possible to sending same message multiple times to the same node?

Tags: omnet++

I want to simulate DOS attack. So, I want to send same message multiple times to a specific node.

For example, when I try to do it in a loop like this:

```
cMessage *msg = new cMessage("data");
cModule *targetNode = getParentModule()->getSubmodule(node[0]);
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    sendDirect(msg, targetNode, "io");
}
```

I am getting this error:

[image: error dos attack]

Is there any way to do that in Omnet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but every time you have to create a [duplicate of the message](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:messages:duplicating-messages) using `dup()`.
So your code may looks like:

```
cMessage *msg = new cMessage("data");
cModule *targetNode = getParentModule()->getSubmodule(node[0]);
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    cMessage * copyMsg = msg->dup();
    sendDirect(copyMsg, targetNode, "io");
}
delete msg; // remove original message (no longer needed)
```

Comment: Just a bit more info: The reason why you have to duplicate the message is that once you've sent a message (which is represented by the message pointer) you will never know when that message is modified or even deleted from the memory by the receiving party. That essentially means that once you send the message, you no longer 'own' it and should not modify, delete or even resend it.